# Drop down list not displaying side by side for voltage, pressure and humidity

Tags: html, html-lists

> Trying to get the voltage, pressure and humidity to display side by side >instead of vertical
>
> Here is the top section of the code that is okay:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="generator" content="CoffeeCup HTML Editor (www.coffeecup.com)">
<meta name="dcterms.created" content="Wed, 20 Feb 2019 14:27:57 GMT">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="keywords" content="">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form name="bda_web" action="" method="get">
<div>
<table width="1200" border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" align="center" bgcolor="6699FF">
<TR><TD COLSPAN=2><pre><b>                                
<center>REMOTE M&C FOR DEHYDRATOR LOCATED AT <input size="11" value="~site~" name="site" cols="7">
<p>LOW-PRESSURE ALARM   &nbsp;<input size="4" value="~HPA~" name="HPA" cols="7">
<p>HIGH-PRESSURE ALARM  &nbsp;<input size="4" value="~LPA~" name="LPA" cols="7">
<p>HUMIDITY ALARM       &nbsp;<input size="4" value="~HUMA~" name="HUMA" cols="7">
<p>RUNTIME ALARM        &nbsp;<input size="4" value="~RTA~" name="RTA" cols="7">
</div>
```

> Here is the section that I need side by side

```
<div>
<body>
<div style="display:block;">
<p>Voltage 
<select>
<option>120V</option>
<option>240V</option>
</select>
<p>Pressure
<select>
<option>1PSI</option>
<option>2PSI</option>
</select>
<p>Humidity
<select>
<option>10P</option>
<option>20P</option>
</select>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

may you want to display in this way

```html
<html>
<div>
<body>
<div style="display:block;">
<p>Voltage 
<select>
<option>120V</option>
<option>240V</option>
</select>
Pressure
<select>
<option>1PSI</option>
<option>2PSI</option>
</select>
Humidity
<select>
<option>10P</option>
<option>20P</option>
</select><p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

check it out..mayb it would work

Comment: pleasure all mine dear